# Borders a few millimeters too wide

Tags: margins, geometry

I want my document to have exactly 3cm space at the left and 2cm to the right and the text to be from one border to the other. However the code below produces a document with 3.1cm border at the left and 2.3cm border at the right. Is there some variable which adds extra space or something similar?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
  \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Make sure that your printer driver doesn't scale the output.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: This seems a problem with the default paper size. What does your PDF previewer tell when you ask for information about the page dimensions?

Comment: @egreg 210x297mm

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I checked my print dialog again and found some hidden scale option which was checked, that solved the problem. Thanks a lot!